Firebase Cloud Messaging Ruby Gem | Payload Deeplinking
I am using the FCM Gem (https://github.com/decision-labs/fcm) to push notifications to our app. I can't workout how to format the payload correctly in order to do deeplinks to either a browser website, or a page in the app. Any ideas?
def send_notification(device_token, notification)

          # Prepare notification data structure
          notification_data = { 
            data: { 
              payload: notification[:payload],
            },             
            token: device_token,
            notification: { 
              title: notification[:alert], 
              body: "", 
            },
            android: {
              notification: {
                color: '#FF0000',
                title: "hello 1" ,
              },
            }
          }
          
          # Send notification with retry on error
          response = with_retry_on_error {
            begin
              response = fcm_client.send_v1(notification_data)


https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#example-notification-click-action?
